# Possible work-around for Chrome clip-path bug with SVG

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I created a minimal example to demonstrate a Chrome bug I recently ran into:

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');

const topHover = document.getElementById('top-hover');
topHover.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#top-clip)');
});
topHover.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#everything)');
});

const bottomHover = document.getElementById('bottom-hover');
bottomHover.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#bottom-clip)');
});
bottomHover.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#everything)');
});

//main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#everything)');
```

```css
#main {
  fill: #51D2C3;
}

#bg {
  fill: #E1F5F2;
}

#top-hover {
  fill: none;
}

#bottom-hover {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="300">
  <path id="bg" d='M100 50 h50 v50 h50 v50 h-50 v50 h-50 v-50 h-50 v-50 h50 z'></path>
  <path id="main" clip-path='url(#everything)' d='M100 50 h50 v50 h50 v50 h-50 v50 h-50 v-50 h-50 v-50 h50 z'></path>
 <g>
    <clipPath id="everything"></clipPath>
    <rect id="top-hover" pointer-events="all" x="50" y="50" width="150" height="75"></rect>
  <clipPath id="top-clip">
      <use href="#top-hover"></use>
  </clipPath>
    <rect id="bottom-hover" pointer-events="all" x="50" y="125" width="150" height="75"></rect>
  <clipPath id="bottom-clip">
      <use href="#bottom-hover"></use>
  </clipPath>
 </g>
</svg>
```

The bug seems to be in how Chrome treats clip-path that's created at the same time as SVG element creation. It seems that whatever is applied to SVG element as initial clip-path becomes a permanent implicit clip-path that can't be unset via JavaScript. I reported it already here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045915

- in Chrome hover states don't work.
- in Firefox they work as expected.
- if you remove clip-path property from object with id="main" in HTML/SVG portion, and set it programmatically via JavaScript (see commented out line), hovering works as expected in Chrome as well.
- if you don't set initial clip-path at all, hovering works as expected in Chrome (aside from starting out in "on" state for all regions)
- if you change initial clip-path to something else (update HTML/SVG clip-path for id="main" element to either url(#top-clip) or url(#bottom-clip)), only the initially non-clipped region will render when new clip-path is applied.

From this, I conclude that that Chrome erroneously treats clip-path that's set at the time of SVG element creation as a permanent implicit clip-path that's applied on top of current clip-path.

This is a simplified example of my actual logic. In my logic I'm creating the above definition via `d3.js`, adding a delay to applying clip-path (even something as low as a microsecond), seems to solve the issue but seems like a hack. Is there a cleaner workaround or an alternative way to define similar functionality that mitigates this bug?

Comment: Setting the initial clip-path property to an empty string and then setting it immediately with JS using `main.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#everything)');` works, but there is a flicker of the empty clip path when the page loads: https://jsfiddle.net/m90y2fhc/

Comment: Correct, if set via JavaScript, the solution is the same as the current work-around I mentioned in last paragraph (I create SVG rendering dynamically via D3, so moving the clip-path application to a `setTimeout()` call does the same thing and avoids this bug at the expense of initial flicker).